nil data passing through to app screen from JSON API data
I’ve read through a number of other posts and replies but still can’t figure out what I’m missing.
I have:
struct Station: Codable {     
  let code: String
  let data: PlantData 
} 

struct PlantData: Codable {
  let batteryPercent: Int 
  let capacity: Float  
  let dayEnergy: Float 
}

…
func getSCPosts (completion: @escaping (PlantData) -> ()) {
 

Which builds the request and then performs the call with:
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        // Handle the response data, error, etc.
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            print("No data received")
            return
        }

        // Parse the response data
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Station.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {completion(json.data)}
            
            print(json.data)
        
        } catch {
            print("Error parsing JSON: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()

If I commentent out the DispatchQueue.main.async line, the print above shows the format of the data in the console as:
PlantData(batteryPercent: 96, capacity: 5.18, dayEnergy: 0.6)

For the view, which I think is where the issue is, I have:
struct SolisCloud: View {
    
    @State var solisResults: PlantData?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Text("My Solis Energy")

            .onAppear{
               getSCPosts(completion: { (solisResults) in self.solisResults = solisResults })
            }
        
        }
    }
}


When I print solisResults in the console I just get 'nil'.
Following a number of posts I’ve found, and various examples from others, I have tried to work out the correct way to pass the data through but for some reason I can’t get my head around it.
I think the issue is with the way I am passing the data received back from the API through to the screen, either in how I am defining solisResults?
I’m probably missing something obvious but any help would be greatly appreciated.

How do you pass getSCPosts(...) to your SolisCloud view? Is that function part of some ObservableObject model, for example? Have a look at this link Managing model data in your app, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app and how to pass data to different views.

I thought that was what @state was doing, storing an instance of the data passed in from the API. Am I missing something? I have another version of this approach working with a different API where the data comes back in an Array which is why I assumed the issues I am having now are related to the format of the data.

Show where you have the function getSCPosts() declared.
Show the full error message you get and on which line of your code.
The solisResults is set/updated as a result of
calling the fuction getSCPosts right. Now, this function needs to be in the
SolisCloud view or passed into it so you can refer to it. In other words,
show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code

Thanks. I’ve got it now. Your first comment was right. The data was not passing through the View. Sorted that now and all pulling through.
